# How to Extract current date & time from user pc TimeZone

Tags: c#

anyone can advise that is there any way by which i can detect country wise time for UK, Germany & France. i am not sure but can we extract country wise time from datetime utc time `DateTime.UtcNow` ?

please advise me because i am in a situation where user can login in to our web site from any country and i need to show time in drop down as per his country current time.

another guy did this way but i am not sure should i follow his approach. here is the url
**http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/7096/**

```
private string GetCountryTime(string country)
    {
        DateTime gmt = default(DateTime);
        System.DateTime value = default(System.DateTime);
        gmt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-330);

        switch (country)
        {
            case "India":
            case "Sri Lanka":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString();
            case "United Kingdom":
            case "Portugal":
            case "Sierra Leone":
            case "Senegal":
            case "Morocco":
            case "Mali":            
                return gmt.ToString();
            case "France":
            case "Spain":
            case "Slovenia":
            case "Slovakia":
            case "Poland":
            case "Nigeria":
            case "Niger":
            case "Hungary":
            case "Denmark":
            case "Czech Republic":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(60).ToString();
            case "Botswana":
            case "Moldova":
            case "South Africa":
            case "Malawi":
            case "Lithuania":
            case "Libya":
            case "Turkey":
            case "Finland":
            case "Egypt":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString(); ;
            case "Bahrain":
            case "Somalia":
            case "Saudi Arabia":
            case "Russia":
            case "Qatar":
            case "Sudan":
            case "Madagascar":
            case "Iraq":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(180).ToString();
            case "Iran":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(220).ToString();
            case "Armenia":
            case "Seychelles":
            case "Reunion":
            case "Oman":
            case "Mauritius":
            case "United Arab Emirates":
            case "Georgia":
            case "Azerbaijan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(240).ToString();
            case "Afghanistan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(270).ToString();
            case "Pakistan":
            case "Maldives":
            case "Kyrgyzstan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(300).ToString();
            case "Nepal":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(345).ToString();
            case "Bangladesh":
            case "Kazakhstan":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(360).ToString();
            case "Myanmar":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(390).ToString();                
            case "Cambodia":
            case "Laos":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(420).ToString();            
            case "Philippines":
            case "Malaysia":
            case "Hong Kong":
            case "China":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(480).ToString();               
            case "Japan":
            case "Korea":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(540).ToString();                
            case "Micronesia":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(720).ToString();               
            case "Papua New Guinea":
            case "Australia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(600).ToString();
            case "New Caledonia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(660).ToString();                
            case "New Zealand":
            case "Fiji":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(720).ToString();
            case "Argentina":
            case "Brazil":
                return  gmt.AddMinutes(-180).ToString();                
            case "Cuba":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-300).ToString();                    
            case "Aruba":
            case "Paraguay":
            case "Netherlands Antilles":
            case "Barbados":
            case "Chile":
            case "Dominican Republic":
            case "Guyana":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "Bahamas":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "Peru":
            case "Panama":
            case "Jamaica":
            case "Haiti":
            case "Colombia":
            case "Canary Islands":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-300).ToString();
            case "Bhutan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(360).ToString();
            case "Belize":
            case "Mexico":
            case "Honduras":
            case "Canada":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-360).ToString();
            case "Nicaragua":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-300).ToString();

            case "United States Of America":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-480).ToString();
            case "French Polynesia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(720).ToString();
            case "Samoa":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-660).ToString();
            case "Singapore":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(480).ToString();
            case "Slovak Republic":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(60).ToString();          
            case "Solomon Islands":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(660).ToString();              
            case "St Helena":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(0).ToString();
            case "St Kitts & Nevia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "St Lucia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();           
            case "Surinam":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-180).ToString();
            case "Swaziland":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString();
            case "Sweden":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(60).ToString();
            case "Switzerland":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(60).ToString();
            case "Syria":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString();
            case "Taiwan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(480).ToString();
            case "Tajikistan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(300).ToString();
            case "Tanzania":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(180).ToString();
            case "Thailand":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(420).ToString();
            case "Tonga":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(0).ToString();
            case "Trinidad & Tobago":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "Tunisia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(60).ToString();          
            case "Turkmenistan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(300).ToString();
            case "Turks & Caicos Islands":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "Tuvalu":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(720).ToString();
            case "Uganda":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(180).ToString();
            case "Ukraine":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString();          
            case "Uruguay":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-180).ToString();
            case "USA":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-480).ToString();
            case "Uzbekistan":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(300).ToString();
            case "Vanuatu":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(660).ToString();
            case "Venezuela":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(-240).ToString();
            case "Vietnam":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(420).ToString();
            case "Wallis & Futuna Islands":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(720).ToString();
            case "Yemen":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(180).ToString();
            case "Zambia":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString();
            case "Zimbabwe":
                return gmt.AddMinutes(120).ToString();
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

thanks

### EDIT

### client side code

after searching lot i got a solution. i can save the user pc timezone in cookie and access that cookie timezone from server side and from there i can get user pc date & time. but there is one risk that user may change their timezone to different one.

```
$(function(){
    setTimezoneCookie();
});


function setTimezoneCookie(){

    var timezone_cookie = "timezoneoffset";

    // if the timezone cookie not exists create one.
    if (!$.cookie(timezone_cookie)) {

        // check if the browser supports cookie
        var test_cookie = 'test cookie';
        $.cookie(test_cookie, true);

        // browser supports cookie
        if ($.cookie(test_cookie)) {

            // delete the test cookie
            $.cookie(test_cookie, null);

            // create a new cookie
            $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());

            // re-load the page
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    // if the current timezone and the one stored in cookie are different
    // then store the new timezone in the cookie and refresh the page.
    else {        

        var storedOffset = parseInt($.cookie(timezone_cookie));
        var currentOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

        // user may have changed the timezone
        if (storedOffset !== currentOffset) {
            $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}

server side code
--------------------
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("timezoneoffset"))
        {
            Session["timezoneoffset"] =
                HttpContext.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"].Value;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

public static string ToClientTime(this DateTime dt)
{
    // read the value from session
    var timeOffSet = HttpContext.Current.Session["timezoneoffset"]; 

    if (timeOffSet != null)
    {
        var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
        dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);

        return dt.ToString();
    }

    // if there is no offset in session return the datetime in server timezone
    return dt.ToLocalTime().ToString();
}
```

### Another way to achieve this task

```
function getTimezoneName() {
    tmSummer = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    so = -1 * tmSummer.getTimezoneOffset();
    tmWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    wo = -1 * tmWinter.getTimezoneOffset();

    if (-660 == so && -660 == wo) return 'Pacific/Midway';
    if (-600 == so && -600 == wo) return 'Pacific/Tahiti';
    if (-570 == so && -570 == wo) return 'Pacific/Marquesas';
    if (-540 == so && -600 == wo) return 'America/Adak';
    if (-540 == so && -540 == wo) return 'Pacific/Gambier';
    if (-480 == so && -540 == wo) return 'US/Alaska';
    if (-480 == so && -480 == wo) return 'Pacific/Pitcairn';
    if (-420 == so && -480 == wo) return 'US/Pacific';
    if (-420 == so && -420 == wo) return 'US/Arizona';
    if (-360 == so && -420 == wo) return 'US/Mountain';
    if (-360 == so && -360 == wo) return 'America/Guatemala';
    if (-360 == so && -300 == wo) return 'Pacific/Easter';
    if (-300 == so && -360 == wo) return 'US/Central';
    if (-300 == so && -300 == wo) return 'America/Bogota';
    if (-240 == so && -300 == wo) return 'US/Eastern';
    if (-240 == so && -240 == wo) return 'America/Caracas';
    if (-240 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Santiago';
    if (-180 == so && -240 == wo) return 'Canada/Atlantic';
    if (-180 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Montevideo';
    if (-180 == so && -120 == wo) return 'America/Sao_Paulo';
    if (-150 == so && -210 == wo) return 'America/St_Johns';
    if (-120 == so && -180 == wo) return 'America/Godthab';
    if (-120 == so && -120 == wo) return 'America/Noronha';
    if (-60 == so && -60 == wo) return 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde';
    if (0 == so && -60 == wo) return 'Atlantic/Azores';
    if (0 == so && 0 == wo) return 'Africa/Casablanca';
    if (60 == so && 0 == wo) return 'Europe/London';
    if (60 == so && 60 == wo) return 'Africa/Algiers';
    if (60 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Africa/Windhoek';
    if (120 == so && 60 == wo) return 'Europe/Amsterdam';
    if (120 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Africa/Harare';
    if (180 == so && 120 == wo) return 'Europe/Athens';
    if (180 == so && 180 == wo) return 'Africa/Nairobi';
    if (240 == so && 180 == wo) return 'Europe/Moscow';
    if (240 == so && 240 == wo) return 'Asia/Dubai';
    if (270 == so && 210 == wo) return 'Asia/Tehran';
    if (270 == so && 270 == wo) return 'Asia/Kabul';
    if (300 == so && 240 == wo) return 'Asia/Baku';
    if (300 == so && 300 == wo) return 'Asia/Karachi';
    if (330 == so && 330 == wo) return 'Asia/Calcutta';
    if (345 == so && 345 == wo) return 'Asia/Katmandu';
    if (360 == so && 300 == wo) return 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';
    if (360 == so && 360 == wo) return 'Asia/Colombo';
    if (390 == so && 390 == wo) return 'Asia/Rangoon';
    if (420 == so && 360 == wo) return 'Asia/Almaty';
    if (420 == so && 420 == wo) return 'Asia/Bangkok';
    if (480 == so && 420 == wo) return 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk';
    if (480 == so && 480 == wo) return 'Australia/Perth';
    if (540 == so && 480 == wo) return 'Asia/Irkutsk';
    if (540 == so && 540 == wo) return 'Asia/Tokyo';
    if (570 == so && 570 == wo) return 'Australia/Darwin';
    if (570 == so && 630 == wo) return 'Australia/Adelaide';
    if (600 == so && 540 == wo) return 'Asia/Yakutsk';
    if (600 == so && 600 == wo) return 'Australia/Brisbane';
    if (600 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Australia/Sydney';
    if (630 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Australia/Lord_Howe';
    if (660 == so && 600 == wo) return 'Asia/Vladivostok';
    if (660 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Pacific/Guadalcanal';
    if (690 == so && 690 == wo) return 'Pacific/Norfolk';
    if (720 == so && 660 == wo) return 'Asia/Magadan';
    if (720 == so && 720 == wo) return 'Pacific/Fiji';
    if (720 == so && 780 == wo) return 'Pacific/Auckland';
    if (765 == so && 825 == wo) return 'Pacific/Chatham';
    if (780 == so && 780 == wo) return 'Pacific/Enderbury'
    if (840 == so && 840 == wo) return 'Pacific/Kiritimati';
    return 'US/Pacific';
}
```

Comment: His approach is plain wrong. First, it will *kinda almost* work only for India, and then it does not take DST into account.

Comment: You realise that code doesn't take into account for Daylight Savings Time? Also, have you heard of [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/)

Comment: What you have at the moment is definitely *not* the way to do this, apart from it not taking into account DST various countries have more than one timezone associated with it (e.g. USA).

Comment: Also, why are you returning your time as a string instead of a normal DateTime object? Save the conversion for the last moment, right before you display it to the user.

Comment: I am SO sorely tempted to give an answer that totally breaks down this code, pointing out all the flaws and defects and bugs.

Comment: is there any way by which i can send country code and it will return current date & time of that country ?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes, it meets the SO criteria and at least has an example of what to achieve.  Save downvotes for problem questions, not ones where you don't agree with the code.

Comment: i am looking for your suggestion that suppose you have a drop down which loads all the countries in the world and 2/3 characters of country code set as dropdown value. requirement is like when user select any country then current date & time need to display in the page. just tell me how developer handle this situation. please guide. thanks

Comment: @Thomas what's the *current time* in Russia? (it spans 9 time zones...)

Comment: really i have no idea but in my prev question i explained my situation and looking for best guidance to handle. need suggestion. thanks

Comment: another idea come to my mind that if i capture client pc timezone by JavaScript by this way Date.getTimezoneOffset(). and pass that timezone to server side routine then how could i extract current date & time of client country. is it possible? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do *not* follow that code. It's terrible code more ways than I have time to go into right now.

Basically, you need to get the time zone that the user is in - which may require more than just the country, as several countries span multiple time zones.

If you want to stick to "vanilla" .NET, you can use `TimeZoneInfo` - you'll need to know the ID of the time zone of the user, at which point you can use:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
var now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zone);
```

Another option is to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library - that allows you to use not just the Windows time zones, but the more widely used [IANA/TZDB](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zones... as well as giving a better date/time API overall, in my view. For example, you'd use:

```
// zoneId is the TZDB ID, e.g. "Europe/London"
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[zoneId];
// clock would be an IClock implementation of some description; rather than
// having a static method, an interface encourages testability. 
ZonedDateTime now = clock.Now.InZone(zone);
```

(Note that in Noda Time 2.0 the IClock interface is changing a bit... the code above is for Noda Time 1.x.)

In both cases, you'd then need to format the `DateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` if you need a string - and what format you use may well be user-specific. In both cases you *also* need to work out the time zone of the user, which can be far from simple. It's hard to give you advice on that aspect of things without knowing what kind of application you're building.

Comment: thanks for answer but is there any way by which i can send country code and it will return current date & time of that country. thanks

Comment: @Thomas As Jon already explained, some countries span multiple timezones. If your country code was for the United States, which time would you expect to get?

Comment: really i have to idea how to achieve this task. writing minimum of code i want to complete this task.looking for your guidance. thanks

Comment: @Jon : i am looking for your suggestion that suppose you have a drop down which loads all the countries in the world and 2/3 character country code set as dropdown value. requirement is like when user select any country then current date & time need to display in the page. just tell me Jon how do you handle this situation. please guide. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not sure how many different ways we can say that it just doesn't work that way. What's the time in the US right now? Well, that depends on whether you're in New York, San Francisco, Hawaii...

Comment: another idea come to my mind that if i capture client pc timezone by JavaScript by this way Date.getTimezoneOffset(). and pass that timezone to server side routine then how could i extract current date & time of client country. is it possible? thanks

Comment: @Thomas: That won't give you the time zone - it will give you the *current* UTC offset, but there can be multiple time zones with the same offset at the same time. I suggest you search for strategies for browser time zone detection - there are JS libraries out there, most of which will give you the IANA/TZDB ID, which you could use with Noda Time.

Comment: @JON : i updated my question with two possible solution to handle timezone issue. please have a loop when possible and tell me which one i should follow. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: If you *only* need the current time, why do you need the server to provide that at all? You could just use the client-side local time. As soon as you need any time other than the current time, the offset isn't going to help you much. But again, I would just use a JS time zone library, probably... I wouldn't bake those time zones into your own code.

Comment: @jon: u said : just use js time zone library...which js library u r talking about.

Comment: @Thomas: There are various ones available. Search for other SO questions.

Comment: i need another guidance that in page load event i need to show client pc date & time but not sure how to achieve it? can we get client pc date & time from request or server variable in asp.net web form. please guide. thanks

Comment: @jon: getTimezoneName() js function attached here looks fine for capturing client pc time zone....what is ur suggestion.

Comment: @Thomas: That `getTimezoneName` looks a bit primitive to me. Just taking two offsets? I wouldn't expect that to be 100% accurate. But if you just want to show the local time on the browser, why not just do that with Javascript? Either way, I think you should probably just see whether the solution you've got so far is good enough for your scenario... and ask another question otherwise. Stack Overflow isn't designed for this sort of continued progressive questioning.

Comment: is it possible to fetch client pc time when page load fire in asp.net webform.....please share the idea. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: That should be posted as a new question.

Comment: @JON apologized asking question on this thread after long time.can we get zoneId by javascript? i got a code which said return timezone id by js...does it work just see script start " function GetUserTimeZoneID(){var timezone=String(new Date());return timezone.substring(timezone.lastIndexOf('(')+1).replace(')','').trim();} " ??

Comment: @Thomas: No, absolutely not. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+timezone+javascript